# Trouble using .closest function

Tags: javascript, jquery, closest

I'm trying to make a sidebar menu for a dashboard. I want to implement this with .closest as it will fit with my code right. Here is a simple example of what I'm trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/eu8kjzh4/10/

Why isn't the closest span's (and the only span in this case) text being replaced with a '-'? In my code, I have

```
$('.' + Key).closest( '.' + Key ).css("color", "#000");
```

This code works just fine, but the one in the jsfiddle does not.

Comment: Both `.sub` and `span` should be inputed as strings, surrounded by `"`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eu8kjzh4/6/ still isn't working

Comment: You have not included jQuery in the fiddle so `$` is not defined. Also the closest method goes up the element tree but the span element is a child of a sibling element so it won't be found. Why does `.closest` _fit with your code right_?

Comment: 1. You seems not including jquery. 2. Maybe use `.siblings` then find `span` would be more suit. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/eu8kjzh4/9/

Comment: I added jQuery. https://jsfiddle.net/eu8kjzh4/10/ going to go look at .siblings now

Comment: The HTML in your fiddle is invalid.

Comment: There's no span in the li's ancestors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) traverses up the DOM and is used for nested elements.

In your markup, your `div` is not a descendant of your span, not even a sibling.

You have
 1. To retrieve the previous sibling (the first `li` after the `body`)
 2. And find the `span` inside the `li`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".sub").prev().find('span').text('-');
});
```

Also, in your fiddle, you forgot to include jQuery.

Here is a working code : https://jsfiddle.net/qwc6pepr/1/

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect function: .closest( selector ) Returns: jQuery
Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree

What you want is the `prev` which finds the first sibling prior to the element

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sub').prev('li').find('span').text('-');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery documentation

> **Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements**, the .closest() method searches through **these elements and their ancestors** in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching elements

Your `span` is neither a Parent Element of your `div.sub` in the DOM, nor matches with the `$(".sub")` rule.

The only way to make your jQuery code work with your HTML structure :

```
$("#plusMinus1").text("-");
```

Or modify your HTML structure to match with the `.closest()` method requierements

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eu8kjzh4/11/)

When you go to the parent you'll end up in the body. From there you can find the span.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".sub").parent().find("span").text("-");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <li>
    <a class="selected" href="#" onclick="return false;">Dashboard 1 <span id="plusMinus1">+</span></a>
  </li>
  <div class="sub">
    <ul>
      <li><a id="s1" href="">Test A</a>
      </li>
      <li><a id="s2" href="">Test B</a>
      </li>
      <li><a id="s3" href="">Test C</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The problem is that if I have multiple spans, then it will replace all of them with a '-'. https://jsfiddle.net/eu8kjzh4/13/ . Is there a way to find the closest span to ".sub" and replace only that?